# Ember validate required input

Tags: validation, ember.js

I have a required input which is connected to a model.

Now i want to show an error message if the required field is empty. But only if the input has been changed or the form gets submitted. So initially there should be no error even if the input is empty.

My current solution is a property named "hasChanged" which gets set by an observer on init.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tovawezide/2/edit?html,js,output

Is there a shorter solution with less boilerplate in ember? like an build in "hasChanged"?
I think my way gets confusing with more inputs.

Note: im not talking about ember-data or its isDirty property nor do i ask for validation libraries.

Comment: Every solution will have some boiler plate that we may need to abstract away as mixin or something. This one uses a computed property http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gopava/1/edit?html,js

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [ember validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) together with [easyForms](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm) quite succesfully for this sort of task.

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  validations: {
    requiredField: {
      presence: true,
    }
  }
});
```

-

```
{{#form-for model}}
  {{input requiredField}}
  {{submit value="Submit" class="button"}}
{{/form-for}}
```